# xgboost on Sagemaker notebook import fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use XGBoost on Sagemaker notebook.

I am using `conda_python3` kernel, and the following packages are installed:

- py-xgboost-mutex
- libxgboost
- py-xgboost
- py-xgboost-gpu

But once I am trying to import xgboost it fails on import:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5943d1bfe3f1> in <module>()
----> 1 import xgboost as xgb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

Comment: Are you sure the notebook is using the correct Python interpreter? Have you checked the value of `sys.executable` ?

Comment: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sagemaker notebooks  use the below steps

#### a) If in Notebook

i)  `!type python3`

ii) Say the above is /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python3 for you

iii) `!/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python3 -m pip install  xgboost`

iv)  `import xgboost`

---

#### b) If using Terminal

i) `conda activate conda_python3`
ii) `pip install xgboost`

Disclaimer :  sometimes the installation would fail with gcc version ,in that case  update pip version before running install