# AWS lambda to run a sagemaker notebook but theres an error with imports via terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a lambda function that runs a notebook on a sagemaker instance. The lambda accesses and runs the notebook but it fails to import packages. The lambda function runs the notebook via terminal so my issue lies there.
As you can see in the image below, datetime and urllib dont throw an error but beautiful soup does. Beautiful soup is installed via lifecylle configuration everytime the instance is started (also via lambda function).

What am i doing wrong please?

[image]

Comment: [sagemaker-notebook-import-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470874/2246345) this might be the installation problem due to python versions on the instance.  You can try those steps in the answer section but [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html) has a warning for package installation.

Comment: <<<<We cannot guarantee that a package installation will be successful. Attempting to install a package in an environment with incompatible dependencies can result in a failure. In such a case you should contact the library maintainer to see if it is possible to update the package dependencies. Alternatively you can attempt to modify the environment in such a way as to allow the installation. This modification however will likely mean removing or updating existing packages, which means we can no longer guarantee stability of this environment.>>>>